# CSS raised border using CSS2

Tags: css

Using current CSS and not CSS3, is there any way of specifying a raised type border style? I would like to somehow emphasize my menu. Basically I am after a border that has has a rounded edge, not rounded corners.

Comment: Something like... an ellipse maybe? Like the central node in this chart? http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/powerpoint/images/charts/7Slide6.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS 2.1 and prior you can use double, ridge, groove, inset, or outset. I've put together a simple demo file for you to play around with and test the various border styles available to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Border Styles</title>
   <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body { background: #999; }
      div { background: #eee; float: left; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; height: 100px; width: 100px; }
      .double { border: 4px double #ccc; }
      .ridge { border: 4px ridge #ccc; }
      .groove { border: 4px groove #ccc; }
      .inset { border: 4px inset #ccc; }
      .outset { border: 4px outset #ccc; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="double">double</div>
   <div class="ridge">ridge</div>
   <div class="groove">groove</div>
   <div class="inset">inset</div>
   <div class="outset">outset</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You cannot make a rounded-corner without the CSS3 spec border-radius property. If you want to do this you should use a script like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to provide alternate support for browsers that cannot support CSS3.

Comment: `inset` and `outset` would do that, but that wouldn't be the *prettiest* result. :P

+1 tho, for the simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Not without images. And CSS3 could be called *current* CSS, at least in implemenation with WebKit and to a lesser extent Gecko.

IE is playing slow paced catch up too :)

You could try and make a raised border by having a few child elements, all with a border and with a lighter shade of colour as you reach the outside border.

Also, you can cause 1px notched corners too with negative margins and CSS. It can also be argued you can make rounded borders without `border-radius`, but the HTML and CSS are quite horrendous (think of all the child elements with negative margins etc)

Comment: IE9 aims to fully support CSS2.  They bragged about it on their website...  On their website they also noted that their competitors are already working on CSS3... *Facepalm*...  It's possible to use `border-radius` but you might as well just use tables... because that's at least much easier to work with...

Comment: @ItzWarty are you able to provide a small sample of how to achieve this using tables - thanks.

Comment: If you could provide an example picture, I might be able to put together an example.